# How do I access members of the Class used to create() an Object in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I want to access the class used to create an object instance from EmberJS. For example, given an an **instance** of the MyWidgetClass in the below example, I'd like to access the myProperty attribute of the class.

```
MyWidgetClass = Ember.View.Extend({});
MyWidgetClass.reopenClass({
  myProperty: 'hihihi'
});
console.log("The myProperty of MyWidgetClass is ", MyWidgetClass.myProperty);

myWidget = MyWidgetClass.create({});
console.log("The myProperty of the Class of myWidget is ",
    myWidget.WHAT_GOES_HERE.myProperty);
```

I want to know what to put in **WHAT_GOES_HERE** on the last line of code. I've tried myWidget._super, myWidget.**proto**, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `constructor` property. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7eJ79/

Answer (score -1):

did you try

`myWidget.get('myProperty');`

Comment: Yup, tried, doesn't do it. The property is on the class, not on the instance.

Comment: is the property on the prototype?